# How to make increment/decrement static variable for an API?

Tags: c++, static-variables

```c
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    static int numelem;
    Test() {}
    ~Test() {}
    int increment();
};

int Test::numelem = 0;

int Test::increment()
{
  return ++Test::numelem;
}
```

So I want to make a counter for my Stacks data structure.
Whenever I push, it increments and when popped it decrements.

My code works, but `int Test::numelem = 0;` is a global variable.
I tried using `inline` but unfortunately I have C++14.

I only put the `static int numelem` instead of the whole `Stack` class to focus on one feature.

Is there an alternative way I can put `int Test::numelem = 0;` inside the class without getting any error?

Comment: With c++14 there is no way of defining a nonconst static data member inside the class. A definition for a nonconst static data member should appear in the same scope in which the class is a way. But with c++17 there is a way. In particular, with c++17 we can use `inline` as you also mentioned in your question.

Comment: Why do you need to? It's going to functionally be a global variable no matter what you do.

Comment: @Heroking18 Do you really want multiple instances of your Stack to share a single counter? Or do you want each instance to have its own counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but `int Test::numelem = 0;` is a global variable.

Technically, it is not a global variable but a *class static* member. Functionally they behave very similarly.

---

> Is there an alternative way I can put `int Test::numelem = 0;` inside the class without getting any error? **unfortunately I have C++14.**

With C++14 the out-of-class definition for a *nonconst* static data member should be in the same **namespace scope** where the class was defined(global namespace in your example). So there is no way of **defining** a *nonconst* static data member inside the class in c++14 as we can't use `inline` in c++14 and the only way of defining a nonconst static data member is to put a definition at namespace scope.

This can be seen from [class.static.data](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.static.data):

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified void. **The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member's class definition**.

---

But with C++17 we can use `inline` to define a non-const static data member inside the class.

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical workaround.  It's particularly useful for templates.

```cpp
class Test {
public:
    static int& numelem() {
        static int val = 0; // or your initializer here
        return val;
    }

    int increment() {
        return ++numelem();
    }
};
```

Of course, now you're accessing it with the syntax `Test::numelem()` instead of just `Test::numelem`.  But something like `++Test::numelem()` still works just fine.